# Ansible: How can I recover only a part of the stdout

Tags: ansible

I want to make a report about my switchs informations but when I do a "show version" on one of my switchs the first 30 lines are not useful. Can I recover only the lines from the line 30 for example ?

```
 tasks:
  - name: Connexion
    ios_command:
      provider: "{{ provider }}"
      commands: show version
    register: config

  - name: Show version
    lineinfile:
     dest: "/etc/ansible/switchs_version.txt"
     line: "{{config.stdout[0] }}" // this line must be changed
```

part 2

I wanted to try something like :

`line: "{{config.stdout[30] }}"`   but it doesn't work like this.

Comment: I think you would need to figure out how to parse the stdout with a filter. Not sure which one to use though. Can you paste the output of config.stdout[0]?  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters

Comment: I think what I need is a CLI filter as you suggest ! Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 0):

When registering task output there are a handful of common return values. You can see a list of the in the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) section of the Ansible documentation.

In your case you want to use the [stdout_lines](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#stdout-lines) return value, which is an array of each stdout line.

```
{{ config.stdout_lines[0] }}
```

Comment: Hello, 
I modified my code and I added '{{ config.stdout_lines[30] }}' but it doesn't work. 

The error was : **fatal: [SIT-69-SPRI-SPE-SW1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 30\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/versionning.yaml': line 23, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - name: Show version\n        ^ here\n"}**

Comment: There are not 30 lines in the output... Try element 0 or running ansible-playbook with the -v flag to see the return values of the previous task.